# Using google or-tools in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, linear-programming, or-tools

[image: Code]

[image: Referenced libraries][image: Error message]I am new to both Eclipse and or-tools.

I have downloaded the binary for or-tools and when I do 'make test_java' (from the terminal), everything runs fine.
However, when I try to use it in eclipse it does not work. I am attaching 3 screenshots showing-

1. The code that I am calling
2. My referenced libraries in the project explorer
3. The error message

I am using Ubuntu 18.03.
Any help would be great. Thanks.

Comment: It is looking for [tag:jna]

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by Greg, it needed a jna.jar file. Downloading and linking it in eclipse solved the problem.